# About compact method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```php
public function index()
{
    $code = '123456789';
    $color = 'Red';
    $cars = ['Ford', 'Oddy', 'Tesla'];
    $hobbies = ['cricket', 'volleyball', 'swimming'];

    return view('posts', compact('code', 'color', 'cars', 'hobbies'));
}
```

Why does the `compact` method use variable names without the `$` sign?

Comment: It's not a Laravel function, it's a PHP function. Check this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 4):

The compact method pulls in the string name of a preceding variable(s).  That's the design of the basic PHP.  If you look at the comments on the method itself, it helps describe a bit more:

> Each parameter can be either a string containing the name of the
>    variable, or an array of variable names. The array can contain other
>    arrays of variable names inside it; compact
>    handles it recursively.

One other note, with PHP 7.3, a breaking change was introduced to this method within PHP - if the variable has not been initialized previous to calling compact, it will fail.  This was not the case previous to 7.3, and thus caused a significant amount of refactoring for many developers.  Beware to initialize your compacted vars if using < 7.3 and plan to upgrade in future.